# Set Builder Notation for Powers of relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, relations

So my relation is z = {(z,z+1)|z ∈ ℤ}

How would I define z^2 in set builder notation?

I know this is how you calculate it but I'm unsure as to how to define it
z^2 = z^1 ∘ z

I was thinking maybe this, but I'm not sure:
a ∘ b | a ∈ s^1 and b ∈ s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, let $R \subseteq A \times A$ be a relation. Then
$$
R^{2} = \{(a,c) \mid \exists b \in A \colon (a,b) \in R \wedge (b,c) \in R \}.
$$
In your specific case we get, setting $Z := \{ (z, z+1) \mid z \in \mathbb Z \}$,
$$
\begin{align*}
Z^{2} &= \{ (a,c) \mid \exists b \in \mathbb Z \colon (a,b) \in Z \wedge (b,c) \in Z \} \\
&= \{ (z, z+2) \mid z \in \mathbb Z\}.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thanks allot, confused myself a little with a silly mistake. I understand it now thanks a bunch!

Comment: @user3768911 You're most welcome. It's easy to get confused about these kinds of notations at first.